# Bypassing Laptop RAM Limitation

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I have looked on the Internet for so long looking for a replacement for my HP Elitebook Workstation. At first, I looked for the HP Z fury Workstation, however, they are crazy expensive. It is true I am looking for:

1- i9 13900HX CPU.
2- 128GB RAM.
3- 4 TB NVMe PCIe SSD.
4- RTX 4090 or A5500.
5- 2.5G LAN (RJ45).
6- WiFi 6E.
7- 17" or more Display.
8- As many ports and expansion slots as possible.

but the HP Z Fury WS price is so unjustified. (five figures)

I work on so many virtual machines + GNS3, so I need a real monster.

Most laptops I found lacked some features.

Recently, I found Dell Alienware M18 with the most specs. however, it only supports a max of 64GB of RAM. I know the CPU definitely supports 128GB RAM, but I do not know why Dell is limiting it. Anyway, I heard that some older Dell limitations have been bypassed. So,

1- Has anyone successfully bypassed this model limitation or know a way to do so safely?
2- Has anyone bought a similar laptop with all the features above, yet not more than $6000 or so? What is it?

Note: It is OK to buy a base laptop and then upgrade it.

Comment: If you want a laptop with those specs it's gonna be crazy expensive no matter what you do. €5000 for a laptop with those specs seems a little on the high side but not unjustified

And about the RAM upgrade, the biggest RAM sticks are 32GB so for 128GB RAM you need 4 slots. If the laptop only has 2 slots you have a hardware limit, not a software limit (which is probably the case with the dell)

Comment: Not 5000, I said five-figure numbers such as 16,000.  I already found laptops with 128GB RAM but with some unavailable feature(s) like RJ45 port and with a much more reasonable price ($6000 or so). For the RAM, I know that Dell in particular has a one-stick 64GB RAM chip (64GB, 1x64GB 5200MT/s CAMM, non-ECC) and I hoped there are others around. At least, I want to make sure if they become more popular in the future I can install them.

Comment: You can get 48 GB DDR5 SODIMMs now so some systems that claim 64GB max due to having 2 slots might really support 96GB with 2x48.